# How to get the value of a column using a dataview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of records and for Employee R1005, I need to check if that Employee has been Enabled for login alert (i.e EnableLoginAlert = Yes), then a button will be displayed.

```
CompanyID      EmployeeNo     EnableLoginAlert    

 10046           R1005              Yes
 20041           Ajax12             No
 47021           Drek               Yes
```

I have tried the below codes:

```
If dCompanyDetails.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

        Dim dataView As DataView = dCompanyDetails.Tables(0).DefaultView
        dataView.RowFilter = "EmployeeNo     = '" & strEmployeeNumber & "'"
    
       
        Dim svalue As String = dataView.Table.Rows(0).ItemArray(0).ToString()

        If svalue = "No" Then
            AlertButton.Visible = False

        ElseIf svalue = "Yes" Then
         {
            //Do something else
         }
        
        End If

End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use a `DataView` then use it. This:

```vb
 Dim svalue As String = dataView.Table.Rows(0).ItemArray(0).ToString()
```

is simply going back to the `DataTable` and using it, ignoring the `DataView`. The `DataView` contains `DataRowView` objects so get the one you need and use it. It is similar to a `DataRow` and you can use it the same way in this case:

```vb
Dim enableLoginAlert = CStr(dataView(0)("EnableLoginAlert")) = "Yes"
```

Now you have an actual `Boolean` that represents the state you want.

That's not how you should do it though. Generally speaking, you would use a `DataView` when you want to bind data. In fact, if you bind a `DataTable` then the data you see in the UI actually comes from the `DefaultView`. That's why you can filter and sort it. In this case, there are better options.

If you want to find a row by its primary key then the `Rows` collection of a `DataTable` has a `Find` method, e.g.

```vb
Dim row = dCompanyDetails.Tables(0).Rows.Find(strEmployeeNumber)
Dim enableLoginAlert = CStr(row("EnableLoginAlert")) = "Yes"
```

If you're searching by other than the primary key, the `DataTable` itself has a `Select` method. Because multiple rows may match, it returns an array, so you need to get the row out of that, e.g.

```vb
Dim row = dCompanyDetails.Tables(0).Select($"EmployeeNo = '{strEmployeeNumber}'").First()
Dim enableLoginAlert = CStr(row("EnableLoginAlert")) = "Yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look up a single row it's perhaps easiest to use LINQ:

```
Dim row = dCompanyDetails.Tables(0).Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r("EmployeeNo").ToString() = strEmployeeNumber)

If row IsNot Nothing AndAlso row("EnableLoginAlert").ToString() = "Yes" Then

  ...
```

..though I'd be the first to claim that using LINQ on base DataTables is very verbose, because of the Cast/AsQueryable. I'd use strongly typed DataTables (in a dataset); if you were to convert your code to using strongly typed tables it would look like:

```
Dim r = someDataSet.AProperTableName.FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.EmployeeNo = strEmployeeNumber)

If r?.EnableLoginALert = "Yes" Then
  ...
```

...using strongly typed datatables is much less messy..

nb: You need to `Imports System.Linq` for these to work

---

That LINQ is the same thing as:

```
For Each r as DataRow in dCompanyDetails.Tables(0) 

  If r("EmployeeNo").ToString() = "R1005" AndAlso r("EnableLoginAlert").ToString() = "Yes" Then
    
      ...
```

---

You also have the option of using `DataTable.Select` (not a LINQ thing, though LINQ has a Select too)

```
Dim matchingRows = dCompanyDetails.Tables(0).Select($"[EmployeeNo] = '{strEmployeeNumber}'")

If matchingrows.Count > 0 AndAlso matchingRows(0)("EnableLoginAlert").ToString() = "Yes"
```